# Wait for a file to be writable

Tags: winapi

I am working on a tool which writes data to files.

At some point, a file might be "locked" and is not writable until other handles have been closed.

I could use the `CreateFile` API in a loop until the file is available for writing access.

But I have 2 concerns using `CreateFile` in a loop:

- The Harddrive (cache) is always running...?!
- I need to call `CreateFile` again to obtain a valid writing handle with different flags...?!

So my question is:

What is the best solution to wait for a file to be writable and instantly get a valid handle?

Are there any event solutions or anything, which allows to "queue/reserve" for a handle once, so that there is no "uncontrolled" race condition with others?

Comment: Hard drives do not have a problem with "always running", it's what they're designed to do...

Comment: @JonathanPotter I disagree. If a harddrive stays at same sector, there will be delays and performance lags. Also it wears out. If such things are handled in memory, it's a different story.

Comment: My comment was a little facetious I'll grant you. But you don't have to worry. The file system is cached in memory. Repeatedly trying to open a file handle will almost certainly not touch the disk.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Actually I would throw into your initial comment that the major concern in that regard is if the harddrive will actually spin up if the server has been running non-stop for X+ years without a power-down.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I almost accept this as an answer. What about the a/the "race" condition? Say 10 processes with different loop times are trying to open the file. Does "first come, first served" apply here? Hard to explain, that's why I threw in the word "queue/reserve" to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A file can be "locked" for two reasons:

1. An actual file lock *which prevents writing to, and possibly reading from* the file.
2. The file being opened without sharing access (accidentially or voluntarily) *which even prevents you from opening a handle*. If you already see `CreateFile` failing, that's likely the case rather than a real lock.

There are conceptually<sup>[1]</sup> at least two ways of knowing that no other process has locked a file without busy waiting:

1. By finding out who holds locks and waiting on the process or thread to exit (or, by outright killing them...)
2. By locking the file yourself

**Who holds locks?**
Finding out about lock owners is rather nasty, you can do it via the *totally undocumented* `SystemLocksInformation` class used with the undocumented `NtQuerySystemInformation` function (the latter is "only undocumented", but the former is so much undocumented that it's really hard to find any information at all). The returned structure is explained [here](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/?p=269), and it contains an owning thread id.

**Luckily**, holding a lock presumes holding a handle. Closing the file handle will unlock all file ranges. Which means: No lock without handle.

In other words, the problem can also be expressed as *"who is holding an open handle to the file?"*. Of course not all processes that hold a handle to a file will have the file locked, but *no process having a handle* guarantees that no process has the file locked.
Code for finding out which processes have a file open is much easier (using restart manager) and is [readily available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/17/10268840.aspx) at Raymond Chen's site.

Now that you know which processes and threads are holding file handles and locks, make a list of all thread/process handles and use `WaitForMultipleObjects` on the list of process handles. When a process exits, all handles are closed.
This also transparently deals with the possibility of a "lock" because a process does not share access.

**Locking the file yourself**
You can use `LockFileEx`, which operates asynchronously. Note that `LockFileEx` needs a valid handle that has been opened with *either* read or write permissions (getting write permission may not be possible, but read should work almost always -- even if you are prevented from actually *reading* by an exclusive lock, it's still possible to create a handle that *could read* if there was no lock).

You can then wait on the asynchronous locking to complete either via the event in the `OVERLAPPED` structure, or on a completion port, and can even do other useful stuff in the mean time, too. Once you have locked the file, you know that nobody else has it locked.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> The wording *"conceptually"* suggests that I am pretty sure either method will work, but I have not tested them.

Comment: Just to clarify the last part of your answer: You suggest that I `CreateFileA()` with `GENERIC_READ` and no sharing and then try to lock it for writing? I need exactly what the OP wants: wait for file to be unlocked, then lock it and do something with it, including writing. I want to wait for it, not poll the status. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @TomášZato: `CreateFile` without sharing access only _apparently_ locks a file insofar as `CreateFile` will fail for someone else attempting, it's not quite the same thing! It doesn't invalidate someone else already holding a handle. Also, if failing is not an option, you cannot really `CreateFile` (to my knowledge) without looping, since it has no "block until success" mode of operation. Once you have a file handle, you **can** however have `LockFileEx` _wait_ until it was able to acquire the lock. That's the default, unless you give `LOCKFILE_FAIL_IMMEDIATELY`. Also note that while ...

Comment: ... (cont) locking _per se_ is certainly possible with _only_ read access to the file, obviously if you actually want to write to the file, you had it better opened with write access. Otherwise, file being locked or not, your writes will not succeed.

Comment: I'm still not clear. Does that mean it's impossible to wait for the file to be available for writing?

Comment: @TomášZato: Short of writing a device driver it is impossible to open a file handle in a blocking manner, for anything. The Windows API allows you to do pretty much everything asynchronously and wait on completion (with the limitation that it is sometimes lying to you. such as completing reads "immediately" which is not as immediately as the word suggests). Everything, except, well, _opening a file handle_. `CreateFile` either succeeds or it doesn't. So, you can wait on `LockFileEx`, no problem. But first you need a handle... so if _"cannot do"_ isn't an option, you must try until successful.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. In this case I will probably just have the whole thing controlled manually, rather than risk race conditions from polling.

Comment: @TomášZato: Well there really is no race condition. You call `CreateFile` and it succeeds, or it doesn't succeed (so you try again, or tell the user "failed!"). That's _annyoing_, but what can you do. Still... no race condition. Then, once you have a valid file handle, you call `LockFileEx` and whenever that returns (or signals the event in your `OVERLAPPED` or posts your completion port), you have the file locked.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from a busy loop, repeatedly trying to open the file with write access (which doesn't smell right - what if the file is locked by a process that is stuck and requires a reboot or manual termination, you'll never be able to write to it.

You could write to a temporary file and rename it afterwards (you can tell the OS a file rename operation is required and it will do it at next boot). If you need to append instead of write, then you'll have to write a process to append your temporary file to the correct one, possibly at startup (write the instructions of which file to append to where to a file that your process reads).

If you need to modify a locked file, then you'll just have to take a lock on it as soon as you can, and refuse to start the program if you don't have write access - warn the user right at the start.

There is a possibility that you can wait in a better way: if a file is locked for writing, you can assume that someone is going to write to it, and so use FindFirstChangeNotification to receive events for the FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE or FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES events. Its not perfect in that someone could request exclusive access for reading too.

I suppose you could try to get the handle to the file that is locked and wait on that, so when it is released your WaitForSingleObject will return. However, there's a good chance you will not be allowed to get the handle owned by a different process (by the security subsystem)

Comment: I have considered that a file could be locked infinitely. I am now more worried about a/the "race" condition... It seems a bit unfair if there are e.g. 2 different loops running and 1 loop is faster than the other and always "steals" a handle which lets the 2nd loop never get a turn. I thought there would be a solution to "reserve" a handle once and check for that, rather than using `CreateFile`