# C#: Process holding named semaphore dies without releasing it

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, synchronization

I am using inter-process synchronization on C#.NET Framework using named semaphore. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace csharp_dot_net_frame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Semaphore semaphoreObject = new Semaphore(initialCount: 1, maximumCount: 1, name: "my_sem");
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for semaphore");
                semaphoreObject.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine("Semaphore lock acquired");
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                semaphoreObject.Release();
                Console.WriteLine("exiting.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran two instances(processes) say `P1` and `P2` of the above code, where `P1` runs first then `P2` and kill the `P1` which has acquired the semaphore without releasing the hold semaphore, then the another process `P2` which was waiting for semaphore on `semaphoreObject.WaitOne();` deadlocks for infinite time. I want that `P2` should definitely get the chance to wait the `semaphoreObject` irrespective of whether `P1` die or not.

The same problem was resolved on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053679/how-do-i-recover-a-semaphore-when-the-process-that-decremented-it-to-zero-crashe) post for UNIX C++ side using `lockf`, wondering if some kind of similar alternative exists in C# as well. I am newbie on C# side, can someone please help me how to resolve this issue on C#.Net.

And also please suggest me the synchronization mechanism on Win32 C++ which is free from above condition of deadlock.

Thanks.

Comment: `lockf` operates on files – you might [try the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685135/open-file-in-exclusive-mode-in-c-sharp).

Comment: A process is not going to signal a semaphore just because you kill it or it dies.  That's not how semaphores work.

Comment: thanks @Aconcagua, Is it possible that when a process is currently reading/writing a file, then other process should wait for its turn for the same file, instead of terminating with exception: **another process is currently accessing that file**?

Comment: @dragon Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406808/wait-for-file-to-be-freed-by-process) is of interest? Hint: If you do a busy wait as proposed there, though, absolutely sleep for some ms within the loop to avoid the CPU being consumed up entirely...

Comment: If willing to go down to WinAPI then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806836/wait-for-a-file-to-be-writable) might be of interest as well.

Comment: Do you actually need semaphore or maybe mutex is enough?

Comment: As much I know, mutex let allow to perform **release** operation only to that process which has performed the **wait** operation on it, so between wait and release we can access the resource. If this is correct, so yeah, mutex would also be a good option. or If my understanding over mutex is incorrect then let me know, thanks.

Comment: Did you try lock?  Lock prevent dead locking of a resource.  Resource can be arrays looping or file reading

Comment: @dragon yes but it doesn't have any counter. One thread can enter, others wait. Why you are using semaphore in the first place? I assumed you have some use for its counter.